# Serving files in directory to uWSGI Flask apps run with Emperor

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

I changed my uWSGI setup to use the Emperor for multi-app deployment. With the old setup when loading 'mypasswords.pwds' file which was saved right next to my app, there was no issue.

Now running everything with the Emperor I get 'No such file or direcotry' errors. This might be because of my setup or because the Emperor simply works in a different way and I'm not sure what's the case.

Directory Tree:

```
Project
    thisismyapp.py
    passwords.pwds
```

Config for uWSGI Emperor:

```
[uwsgi]
# Variables
base = /var/www/Project

# Generic Config
home = %(base)/venv
pythonpath = %(base)
socket = /tmp/%n.sock
module = thisismyapp:app # Is this an issue?
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log
```

Traceback:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.11.2 (64bit) on [Thu Feb  4 00:41:47 2016] ***
compiled with version: 4.9.2 on 24 October 2015 23:42:32
os: Linux-3.19.0-42-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 17 22:54:45 UTC 2015
nodename: website
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
your processes number limit is 1868
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /tmp/project.sock fd 3
Python version: 2.7.9 (default, Apr  2 2015, 15:37:21)  [GCC 4.9.2]
Set PythonHome to /var/www/Project/venv
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x17355e0
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 145520 bytes (142 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
added /var/www/Project/ to pythonpath.
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 1 seconds on interpreter 0x17355e0 pid: 6772 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 6772)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 6779, cores: 1)
[pid: 6779|app: 0|req: 1/1] 79.227.145.119 () {46 vars in 967 bytes} [Thu Feb  4 00:41:51 2016] GET / => generated 3552 bytes in 355 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 2 headers in 81 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
announcing my loyalty to the Emperor...
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'passwords.pwds'
```

Python file access:

```
f = open('passwords.pwds', 'r')
```

Comment: Please post the entire traceback

Comment: Ofc I knew I forgot smth :D

Comment: This looks ok .. as your webui process is successfully running with uwsgi, please check your `thisismyapp.py` and see if you passed in relative paths to the `passwords.pwds` file.

Comment: Added how I am accessing the file. This looks fine to me and should work since it did in fact work before and it works when running it without uwsgi flask only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
from os import path

passwords_location = path.join(path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__), 'passwords.pwds'))
with open(passwords_location) as f:
    do_something()
```

Your original way using the relative location, so may can't find the file if you're not in the Project folder. Also, use `with` block is a better way to handle files, it will ensure to close the file when exit the context block.

Comment: You're right I should have done it this way in the first place. I'll try it out ASAP. It's still a little weird to me. Does uwsgi execute the files from a certain location?

Comment: I guess it is `current working directory: /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled`, but not sure about that. Please correct me if I was wrong.